# javascript override css display: none visible hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a CSS id that both hides visibility and displays: none. When I click the button I would like for it to display. However, the only way I am able to make it work is by removing the display:none. I do not want this because it is an invisible element causing design to be messed up.

Ultimately the goal is to click button, make some elements disappear and some elements appear.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="fwork1" id="fwork1">

    <a href="#portfolio" onclick="fWork1()">
        <img src="assets/img/portfolio/corinthmc/corinthmc_small.png" alt=""> 
    </a>

</div>

<div id="hwork1">

    <p>some text</p>

</div>

<div id="fWorkReturn">

    <button onclick="fWorkReturn()">Click</button>

</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
#hwork1 {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

Here is the Javascript

```
function fWork1() {
    document.getElementById("fwork2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("fwork3").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("fwork4").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("hwork1").style.display = "block"; 
}

function fWorkReturn() {
    document.getElementById("fwork1").style.display = "initial";
    document.getElementById("fwork2").style.display = "initial";
    document.getElementById("fwork3").style.display = "initial";
    document.getElementById("fwork4").style.display = "initial";
    document.getElementById("hwork1").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vm5xejhm/)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to handle this would be to add a class when you click on you element. your js would look like this:

```
function fWork1() {
    document.getElementById("fwork2").classList().add('active');
}
```

and you CSS will look like this:

```
#hwork1 {
    display: none;
}

#hwork1.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: `display: visible` is not valid. `display: block` and `visibility: visible` would work.

Comment: apologies as I may be a little slow at understanding. I added class="active" to the id="hwork1" I then added the JS - function fWork1() {
    document.getElementById("fwork2").classList().add('active');
} not understanding what fwork2 is used for in this instance. When I used display: block it wasn't physically visible, but was causing disruption as being there in the design. I did use visibility: visible and it seemed to be hidden, but again I could not get it visible on click.

Comment: I am still having no luck. hwork1 is still not showing up.

Comment: it looks like your `onclick=()` isn't working on your button. When add this script in your html file you should get what you want. also change you onclick function to active() and this will work: `<script>
function active() {
 if(document.getElementById("hwork1").classList.contains('active')) {
   document.getElementById("hwork1").classList.remove('active');
  } else {
   document.getElementById("hwork1").classList.add('active');
  }  
}
</script>`

Comment: @SkylarWuebkerhow do I reverse it. It seems to work, but I need to reverse it back to display: none - hidden when another button is clicked.

Comment: I just figured it out, thanks everyone for your input. Learned me something today. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this -

```js
function hide() {
  document.getElementById("fwork2").style.visibility = "";
  document.getElementById("fwork3").style.visibility = "";
  document.getElementById("fwork4").style.visibility = "";
  document.getElementById("hwork1").style.visibility = "";
}

function show() {
  document.getElementById("fwork1").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("fwork2").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("fwork3").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("fwork4").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("hwork1").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Comment: You made the visibility hidden when clicked, when it's already hidden from the css.

Comment: @SrgSprinkles removed unwanted css code, but still these will solve design messing up problem

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can change the visibility of an element with JavaScript. The current code changes the visibility property of some elements when the function is called / button is clicked. It should be fairly straightforward how to apply this in another context.

```js
function hideFourAndShowSix(){
  let four = document.getElementById('four');
  let six = document.getElementById('six');
  six.style.setProperty('visibility', 'visible');
  six.style.setProperty('display', 'list-item');
  four.style.setProperty('visibility', 'hidden');
}
```

```css
#six{
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li id="four">Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li id="six">Six</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="hideFourAndShowSix()">Hide no. 4 and show no.6</button>
```

PS: If you need extra explanation drop in a comment ;).

Comment: it makes complete sense what you are saying, but basically that is what I am already doing. I can make the elements that I want hodden. I can even bring them back. My issue is that I have a hidden element in CSS I do not want to show using visibility: hidden;
    display: none; - the element I want to show doesn't show when button is clicked. How do I override the display:none in js?

Comment: @tmoflash You would have to set the `display` property to the value it should be ( usually `inline`, `block`, `inline-block`, but there are many more). Unfortunately you do have to know which one to use. ( Unless you can add the initial `display: none` in a class that is assigned to hidden elements. Then you can remove that class with JavaScript and get the default value again )