# Javascript display none property not being triggered the second time

Tags: javascript, dom

I am using the `onclick` method on a `<button/>`, on game start and restart. I am making the `<button/>`'s parent node's `display: none` on that click. It works the first time when I click (i.e start the game) but after the game is over, when I try to restart the game using the same `<button/>`, the `display: none` property is not working.

In the JavaScript part, I am clicking the `<button/>`, then doing some animation and when the animation stops, when I try to restart it the `display: none` property is not working.

**HTML part of the `<button/>` and its parent node

```js
const startButton = document.getElementById("play-start");

const gameAnimation = new GameAnimation(parentElement);
window.addEventListener("keydown", gameAnimation.moveCar);

startButton.onclick = () => {
  startButton.parentNode.style.display = "none";
  gameAnimation.init();
};
```

```html
<div class="game-start-play" id="game-start-play">
  <button id="play-start">Click to play</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just `document.getElementById("game-start-play").hidden = true`

Comment: you should fetch element each time from documnet and not using reference! i mean write document.getElem... instead of using startButton.parent...

Comment: try `none !important`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript override css display: none visible hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50496621/javascript-override-css-display-none-visible-hidden)